# How can I shorten a URL?

Tags: url

How can I shorten a URL, so even when it is clicked on it will still show the short version and not the full version of the URL? I want to have a website or an app where I can shorten the url and the full one won't be shown when users click on it. The browser will still show the shortened version, without expanding it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is generally only possible if you are using a 3rd party URL shortening service that supports cloaking, or you are implementing your own URL shortening server.

You can certainly put a short URL in your HTML, and the user will only see the short URL when hovering over the link.  But, as soon as the link is clicked, the browser is going to navigate to the short URL.

If you are using a 3rd party shortening service without cloaking, it is just going to redirect the browser to the long URL, and then the browser will display that URL in its address bar.

If you are using a shortening service with cloaking, the typical implementation will simply return an HTML frame that refers to the long URL.  Visually, the user won't see any difference, and the browser will display the short URL in the address bar since that is the URL actually being displayed, but the frame will then pull in content from the long URL.  The user can easily determine the long URL by simply looking at the HTML source of the frame, or at the properties of the page the frame is displaying.

To truly hide the long URL completely, the service that processes the short URL navigation will have to retrieve the actual content located at the long URL and then send it back to the browser as if it were the content of the short URL.  Most shortening services will not do that, but you could try setting up your own server that does.